# Understanding Make's implicit rules

Tags: makefile

If I erase the gcc lines from this file shouldn't it take compilation as the implicit rule? Why isn't it allowing me to run the program `./calc` with that makefile configuration?

Makefile:

```
all: calc 

clean:  
    rm -rf calc arit.o calc.o

calc:   calc.o arit.o
    #gcc -o calc calc.o arit.o

calc.o: calc.c arit.h
    #gcc -c calc.c 

arit.o: arit.c arit.h
    #gcc -c arit.c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the comment is indented by a tab stop, it is treated as a command (and executed by the shell, which treats it as a comment).

If the '#' symbols were in column 1, then they would be pure (make) comments.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Jonathan Leffler's answer, the following minimal `GNUMakefile` should do all compilation and linking through implicit rules only:

```
calc: calc.o arit.o
arit.o: arit.c arit.h
calc.o: calc.c arit.h
clean:
    rm -rf calc arit.o calc.o
```

Comment: Interesting: I was not aware that you could omit the link line commands with GNU Make.  There are some versions of Make where that would not be possible - for instance, Solaris make, and I believe POSIX make does not guarantee that.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules does not list it as a non-POSIX feature (look for "Linking a single object file"). I built `make` from the heirloom project and tested that and it also links both objects, so I'd guess that it's reasonably portable.

Comment: Define 'reasonably portable'.  It does not work on Solaris 10 make.   It does not work on HP-UX 11.11 make.  It does not work on AIX 5.3 make.  That leaves Linux and MacOS X, which both use GNU make, as the systems where it does work.  **YMMV**.  I note that the manual says "This rule does the right thing for a simple program with only one source file. It will also do the right thing if there are multiple object files (presumably coming from various other source files), one of which has a name matching that of the executable file."  That is no longer 'linking a single object file'.

Comment: FWIW: On HP-UX and Solaris, make doesn't try to run a link command; on AIX, make runs a single-object link command ('`cc -O calc.c -o calc`').

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Touché. My instinct was to reach for heirloom make as some representative of strict standards compliance, which turned out to be incorrect.